# Setting up playgroups

Tags: excel, vba

UPDATED FOR PARTICIPANTS.

For years I have been annoyed with the returning task of having to set up playgroups for my kids classes. Now having 3 kids this task is a bit daunting. Hence, great if an automatization can be implemented.

Below is the problem for one of the classes, great if it can be more flexible regarding number of participants, groups and occurrences.

Information:

- Playgroups will occur 10 times during a year
- Playgroups will be reshuffled for each occurrence
- Participant pool is:
  - 13 boys
  - 9 girls
- Create 5 groups with 4-5 participants for each Playgroup occurrence
- Minimum 2 boys and 2 girls in each group
- If the minimum cannot be achieved, then only one sex is a group (in this case there will be a girls group of 4 participants)
- Optimal solution will have fewest overlap of participants across occurrences.

I have a preference for the solution / toolbox to be in excel (with VBA if needed).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [Ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: You seem to have sufficient constraints to control the situation, you should check out the Solver - available in Excel.

Comment: @SolarMike which solver are you talking about?

Comment: @GWD the one in Excel, see Tools : Solver. If it is not there then you need to add it (Addins)...

Comment: With 9 boys but 5 groups and 2 boys per group minimum that means you are 1 boy short.

Comment: @SolarMike but you can do a group of 3 boys / 2 girls and one of only girls, as allowed by the problem description.

Comment: Hi all. There need to be a solution where one group is solely girls in the above, ie if the minimum constraint cannot be achieved, then none of the particular sex (girl or buy) alternatively a solution cannot have a single girl or boy.

Comment: I have been giving the problem quite a bit of thought as to an algorithm but have a hard time figuring out how to optimize across the number of parameters in an efficient way - by utilizing excel/VBA.

Comment: Yeah I see the issue, somehow my brain malfunctioned and had the participants wrong and hence making the constraints void. There are 13 boys and 9 girls. So the constraint is probably best set along the lines of: Groups 1-4; 2<= #M <=5 AND 2<= #F <= 3. And Group 5 could be F = 0 and M => 4

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is really an excel or vba question, more of a general question about an algorithm. The problem you describe is non-trivial and related to the [social golfer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_golfer_problem) which has been proven to be NP-complete, so very difficult to solve for larger amounts of people/groups.

For your parameters, the social golfer problem in its original form (no two people can ever be in the same group twice) is obviously unsolvable, so you have to specify what you want "minimum overlap" to mean. It can either mean "maximize the number of overall contacts" so every child should be in the same group with every other child at least once. This seems achievable pretty easily with your parameters.

Alternatively you can try to minimize a "penalty score" aka each child should be in the same group as every other child at least once, but **not more than once**. Being in the same group two or more times will increase the "penalty score" which you try to minimize. This is certainly a valid option for your problem.

Luckily there is a website that allows you to determine a schedule just like this, however, it can't fulfill your requirement of an even boy/girl distribution. The website can be found [here](https://goodenoughgolfers.com/): https://goodenoughgolfers.com/

I once wrote a solver for this problem myself, including the boy/girl distribution requirement, but it is still very bare bone and just available as source code in `c++` [here](https://github.com/guwidoe/PeopleDistributor).

I computed the following distributions with my tool and adapted the result manually to fit your criteria:

**Day 1**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 1 | Boy 2 | Boy 3 | Boy 4 |  |
| Boy 6 | Boy 7 | Boy 8 | Boy 9 |  |
|  |  |  | Boy 5 |  |
| Girl 1 | Girl 2 | Girl 3 | Girl 4 | Girl 5 |
|  | Girl 7 | Girl 8 | Girl 9 | Girl 10 |
| Girl 11 |  |  |  | Girl 12 |
|  |  |  |  | Girl 6 |

**Day 2**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Boy 1 |  | Boy 9 | Boy 4 |
| Boy 3 | Boy 5 |  |  |  |
| Boy 6 | Boy 8 |  | Boy 7 | Boy 2 |
|  |  | Girl 9 | Girl 2 | Girl 12 |
| Girl 5 | Girl 4 | Girl 10 |  |  |
| Girl 3 | Girl 11 | Girl 8 | Girl 7 | Girl 6 |
|  |  | Girl 1 |  |  |

**Day 3**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 8 |  | Boy 5 |  | Boy 9 |
| Boy 3 |  | Boy 6 | Boy 1 | Boy 7 |
|  |  |  | Boy 4 | Boy 2 |
|  | Girl 3 |  |  |  |
| Girl 9 | Girl 12 | Girl 8 | Girl 7 | Girl 5 |
| Girl 6 | Girl 2 | Girl 1 | Girl 10 | Girl 4 |
|  | Girl 11 |  |  |  |

**Day 4**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 5 |  |  |  |  |
| Boy 9 |  | Boy 1 | Boy 8 | Boy 6 |
| Boy 2 |  | Boy 3 | Boy 4 | Boy 7 |
| Girl 12 | Girl 1 | Girl 10 | Girl 2 | Girl 6 |
| Girl 3 | Girl 8 | Girl 11 |  | Girl 9 |
|  | Girl 4 |  | Girl 5 |  |
|  | Girl 7 |  |  |  |

**Day 5**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 5 | Boy 3 | Boy 7 | Boy 6 |  |
|  | Boy 9 | Boy 1 | Boy 8 |  |
| Boy 4 |  |  | Boy 2 |  |
| Girl 5 |  | Girl 9 | Girl 3 | Girl 11 |
|  | Girl 4 | Girl 2 | Girl 10 | Girl 1 |
| Girl 8 | Girl 12 |  |  | Girl 7 |
|  |  |  |  | Girl 6 |

**Day 6**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 8 | Boy 4 | Boy 2 |  |  |
| Boy 5 | Boy 3 | Boy 1 | Boy 6 |  |
|  | Boy 7 |  | Boy 9 |  |
|  | Girl 9 | Girl 8 | Girl 6 | Girl 5 |
| Girl 3 |  |  | Girl 10 | Girl 7 |
| Girl 12 | Girl 1 | Girl 11 |  | Girl 4 |
|  |  |  |  | Girl 2 |

**Day 7**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 2 |  |  | Boy 3 | Boy 7 |
|  | Boy 8 |  | Boy 4 | Boy 1 |
| Boy 6 | Boy 9 |  | Boy 5 |  |
| Girl 9 | Girl 8 | Girl 1 | Girl 4 |  |
|  |  | Girl 5 |  | Girl 10 |
| Girl 3 | Girl 7 | Girl 2 | Girl 6 | Girl 12 |
|  |  | Girl 11 |  |  |

**Day 8**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 5 |  | Boy 7 | Boy 8 | Boy 4 |
| Boy 2 |  | Boy 1 |  | Boy 3 |
|  |  |  | Boy 9 | Boy 6 |
| Girl 1 | Girl 12 | Girl 7 | Girl 10 | Girl 11 |
|  | Girl 5 |  |  | Girl 2 |
| Girl 3 | Girl 8 | Girl 9 | Girl 6 |  |
|  | Girl 4 |  |  |  |

**Day 9**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 6 | Boy 7 |  | Boy 9 |  |
| Boy 1 | Boy 3 |  |  | Boy 4 |
|  | Boy 8 |  | Boy 2 | Boy 5 |
| Girl 6 |  | Girl 2 |  | Girl 1 |
|  | Girl 10 | Girl 8 | Girl 7 | Girl 12 |
| Girl 4 | Girl 9 | Girl 3 | Girl 5 |  |
|  |  | Girl 11 |  |  |

**Day 10**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boy 4 |  | Boy 6 | Boy 1 | Boy 2 |
|  |  | Boy 7 | Boy 5 | Boy 3 |
| Boy 9 |  | Boy 8 |  |  |
|  | Girl 12 | Girl 2 | Girl 7 |  |
| Girl 5 | Girl 8 |  |  | Girl 3 |
| Girl 11 | Girl 9 | Girl 10 | Girl 6 | Girl 1 |
|  | Girl 4 |  |  |  |

Comment: With 5 per group then M/F cannot be even...

Comment: @SolarMike of course not, but you can at least try to get it approximately even or like described in the question. I'm checking out the solver add-in you mentioned. It's interesting, I hadn't heard of it!

Comment: I believe the optimal solution minimizes the number of overlaps. They are allowed, but should be minimized. There should be no preferential treatment to any single participant, eg application of utility function.

Comment: @Tankpasser then I think your best option is to use the website I linked in my answer and tweak the results manually to fit your extra criteria. If you want I can run my C++ solution for your problem, however, it too can not match your last criterion of not allowing a group with only 1 boy. So the solution will still have to be tweaked manually.

Comment: @Tankpasser check out the example distribution I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, set this up as a basic control.
You can add extra constraints as you need, such as controlling the number of M and F in each group, be good practice for you.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this mask is insufficient to solve this. The problem is, that each distribution also depends on all the other distributions, you can't calculate them independently. So you need this but times ten for the parameters he gave us. And then you have to connect all these 10 distributions and optimize the value of any two people being in the same group in multiple of these 10 distributions to be as small as possible. To me, it seems very complicated to set up in solver, but maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @GWD so add a constraint which effectively removes groups already attended by each participant

Comment: I don't think how often say person 1 has been in say group "1" is relevant, because the group numbers mean nothing, all we care about is who else has been in group 1 at the same time as person 1. If everyone else changes group and person 1 stays in group 1 that's perfectly fine from the perspective of this problem. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I still don't know how your solution is supposed to work

Comment: Somehow my brain malfunctioned and had the participants wrong and hence making the constraints void. There are 13 boys and 9 girls. So the constraint is probably best set along the lines of: Groups 1-4; 2<= #M <=5 AND 2<= #F <= 3. And Group 5 could be F = 0 and M => 4

Comment: So I guess utilizing the excel solver path and adding the correct grouping constraints, one need to make some matrix comparison of intersections between participants with potentially running this via some VBA? Or can it be done dynamically in excel and subject to executing the solver?